# Routing one machine's traffic through GRE tunnel to a remote NAT

Tags: nat, tunnel, gre

I had to solve the following dilemma for a friend and thought I'd document how we did it here...

Here's the situation:

- His home network `192.168.1.0/24` and it sits behind a Linux router that performs NAT and has public IP address `A.A.A.A`. The Linux router runs openSUSE 15.3.
- On the home network there is one particular device of interest at address `192.168.1.17`.
- He has a remote Linux machine that sits by itself on the Internet at address `B.B.B.B`. This machine is a hosted server and lives in another part of the country. This machine also runs openSUSE 15.3.

What he wants is for all of `192.168.1.17`'s traffic to be routed through, and NAT'd by, the remote machine `B.B.B.B`, but for all the other machines on the home network to be unaffected (i.e., still routed through the home router `A.A.A.A` as usual).

The effect is that to the outside world all of `192.168.1.17`'s traffic will appear to be coming from `B.B.B.B` instead of `A.A.A.A`.

This as the NAT/networking equivalent of "[throwing your voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventriloquism)" for one particular machine on your network.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we did this.

We set up a GRE tunnel between `A.A.A.A` and `B.B.B.B` (interface `gre1` on both servers), with internal point-to-point tunnel IP addresses `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2` (respectively). Note there's no need for encryption because the packets in the tunnel are just going to be unwrapped and sent over the Internet as-is anyway.

Next, we have to configure `B.B.B.B` to enable `NAT` on its external interface `eth0`. This is done via `firewalld`. We then have to add a custom rule to `firewalld` to not block the incoming GRE packets. We put the `gre1` interface into the `trusted` zone so all of the packets arriving inside the tunnel are allowed, and will get NAT'd.

On the home network, we were already setup via `firewalld` as a NAT router so the only things left to do were (a) create the other side of the GRE tunnel, and (b) make Linux divert `192.168.1.17`'s outgoing traffic into the tunnel. This last step is the slightly tricky part.

Details below...

#### Setup on `B.B.B.B` (Remote Server)

Add interface `gre1`:

```sh
    # /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-gre1
    STARTMODE='onboot'
    BOOTPROTO='static'
    TUNNEL='gre'
    TUNNEL_LOCAL_IPADDR='B.B.B.B'
    TUNNEL_REMOTE_IPADDR='A.A.A.A'
    IPADDR='10.0.0.2'
    REMOTE_IPADDR='10.0.0.1'
    TUNNEL_TTL='64'
    ZONE=trusted
```

Add route to home network and remote side of P2P link via `gre1`:

```
    # /etc/sysconfig/network/ifroute-gre1 
    # Destination   Gateway     Netmask     Interface   Options
    192.168.1.0/24  -           -           -
    10.0.0.1        -           -           -
```

Configure `firewalld` via `yast2 firewall`

- Put interface `eth0` in zone `external`
- Put interface `gre1` in zone `trusted`
- Add a custom firewall rule to zone `external` allowing incoming GRE packets from `A.A.A.A`
- Add custom firewall rules to clamp TCP MSS to both `external` and `trusted` zones (requires `firewalld >= 1.0.0`)

Zone files in `/etc/firewalld/zones`:

```xml
    # /etc/firewalld/zones/external.xml    
    <zone>
        <short>External</short>
        <service name="ssh"/>
        ...
        <masquerade/>
        <rule family="ipv4">
          <source address="A.A.A.A"/>
          <accept/>
        </rule>
        <rule>
          <tcp-mss-clamp value="1420"/><!-- requires firewalld >= 1.0.0 -->
        </rule>
        <interface name="eth0"/>
    </zone>
```

```xml
    # /etc/firewalld/zones/trusted.xml    
    <zone target="ACCEPT">
      <short>Trusted</short>
      <description>All network connections are accepted.</description>
      <rule>
          <tcp-mss-clamp value="1420"/><!-- requires firewalld >= 1.0.0 -->
      </rule>
      <interface name="gre1"/>
    </zone>
```

#### Setup on `A.A.A.A` (Home Network Server)

This assumes that `A.A.A.A` is already setup to NAT the `192.168.1.0/24` network, etc.

Add interface `gre1`:

```sh
    # /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-gre1
    STARTMODE='onboot'
    BOOTPROTO='static'
    TUNNEL='gre'
    TUNNEL_LOCAL_IPADDR='A.A.A.A'
    TUNNEL_REMOTE_IPADDR='B.B.B.B'
    IPADDR='10.0.0.1'
    REMOTE_IPADDR='10.0.0.2'
    TUNNEL_TTL='64'
    ZONE='trusted'
```

Add route to remote side of P2P link via `gre1`:

```
    # /etc/sysconfig/network/ifroute-gre1 
    # Destination   Gateway     Netmask     Interface   Options
    10.0.0.2        -           -           -
```

Configure `firewalld` via `yast2 firewall`:

- Put interface `gre1` in zone `trusted`
- Interface `eth0` should already be in zone `external`

### Activating The Rerouting

This is the final "tricky part" which causes `192.168.1.17`'s outbound traffic to be diverted through the GRE tunnel.

To turn on the redirection, run these commands on `A.A.A.A`:

```
$ ip route flush table 10
$ ip route add table 10 to default via 10.0.0.2 dev gre1
$ ip rule add from 192.168.1.17 table 10 priority 10
```

To undo the above commands:

```
$ ip rule del from 192.168.1.17 table 10 priority 10
$ ip route flush table 10
```